How do most popular DEs handle external monitor connection?
I've recently moved from using Cinnamon desktop environment to i3wm (quite a leap, I know). The first thing I've immediately noticed is that i3 doesn't handle external monitor connection automatically. I've spent some time googling around, and found out that all of the fixes suggest some form of manually connecting external output through xrandr (either writing xrandr --output … to the i3 config file; or running a script in the background, which checks if the external monitor is connected every 5 seconds, again, with xrandr — which is just bad programming).
At the same time, all the DEs that I've tried to that point handled external monitor connection automatically: you just plug in the monitor, and it switches on immidiately.
Then out of curiosity I've started to check other popular DEs, and noticed that xfce behaves the same way i3 does.
So there are my questions. How do KDE and Gnome handle external monitor connection automatically? And why i3 and xfce do not behave the same way? Perhaps, there is some sort of monitor-connection event, that is lacking in both i3 and xfce? And is it possible to implement for i3 the behaviour that is similar to KDE and Gnome?

XFCE does handle this beautifully unless you've disable it manually. Settings -> Display -> Advanced -> Connecting Displays, When New Displays are connected: Options.

i3wm is just a window manager, not a desktop environment. That's why Gnome and i3wm differ here: things that are not immediately related to managing windows are simply of no concern to it. Plugging in screens, showing you when you got disconnected from the network, starting a sound server: not the job that i3 fulfills.
But: I can't confirm XFCE doesn't immediately recognize plugged in monitors; just as Artem in your comments, this just works out of the box for me, just as it does on Gnome, KDE, Cinnamon.
So, you'd want a desktop environment with i3wm as window manager! I've done similar before, combining awesomewm with a cinnamon session, or with xfce4 (but then you'll need to figure out what goes wrong with XFCE). Both works; I'm currently typing on awesomewm with a cinnamon session.
Was pretty straightforward to set up:

install cinnamon
make a new file /usr/share/cinnamon-session/sessions/cinnamon-i3wm.session, contents
[Cinnamon Session]
Name=Cinnamon i3wm
RequiredProviders=windowmanager;
DefaultProvider-windowmanager=i3

should belong to root, be writable by root and readable by all, ie. 0644.

I think that was all, because i3 packages usually do install /usr/share/applications/i3.desktop; it that's missing, this is what it should look like:
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=i3
NoDisplay=true
GenericName=A dynamic tiling window manager
Comment=improved dynamic tiling window manager
Exec=i3
X-GNOME-WMName=i3
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=WindowManager
X-GNOME-Provides=windowmanager
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=false

restart your login manager (might be easiest to just reboot), and select the "Cinnamon i3wm" session.

So I've tried to play around with installing i3 over a Cinnamon installation, and found out that login manager doesn't even add new session entries that I create at /usr/share/cinnamon-session/sessions. Also, Archwiki gives that Cinnamon doesn't support swapping Cinnamon's native wm (Muffin)

@AlexanderN. as already said, I'm literally using cinnamon-session with awesomewm right and not muffin, so Archwiki is wrong there (as quite commonly the case, sadly), or we need to interpret "support" in a different way.

@AlexanderN. your distro might configure cinnamon-session to look elsewhere. Check the output of cd /usr/share; find -iname '*.session'
